# Error after creating pdf/a

Tags: pdf, pdf-a

I must create my thesis in `pdf/a` format. I'm using the package `pdfx` calling in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
```

When I open the pdf with Adobe I got the blu bar says me that file is in PDF/A format. Unfortunately when I validate the file using always Adobe I got many strange error. I don't know how to resolve the problem.

here it is the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace} %setta l'interlinea a 1,5
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{lipsum}

%PDF METADATA
%-----------------------------
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{Ttitle}
\Author{Salvatore Mazzarino}
\Keywords{Mobile Cloud\sep
Energia\sep
Green Networking\sep
Network Coding\sep
User Cooperation\sep
RLNC\sep}
\Org{Università degli Studi di Catania} 
\end{filecontents*}
%-----------------------------

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Here it is the errors I got:

[image]

```
Validating file "prova.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-1b
The separator after an 'obj' must be an EOL. (2)
The separator before an 'endobj' must be an EOL. (2)
The separator before 'endstream' must be an EOL.
XML line 21:27: Input is not proper UTF-
Bytes: 0xE0 0x20 0x64 0x65.", 1
The value of the key N is 4 but must be 3.
The document does not conform to the requested standard.
The file format (header, trailer, objects, xref, streams) is corrupted.
The document doesn't conform to the PDF reference (missing required entries, wrong value types, etc.).
The document's meta data is either missing or inconsistent or corrupt.
Done.
```

[image]

Comment: Well I resolved the last two problems. It was an png file...the other problem I don't know how to resolve it...

Comment: valitade it with a pdf/a online validator I got the errors above

Comment: @HarishKumar please try to validate it online with this validator:http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx

Comment: The UTF problem is surely caused by an encoding problem: `0xE0 0x20 0x64 0x65` is the string `à de` in Latin-1 encoding and seems to come from `Università degli Studi`. Ensure that the `.xmpdata` file is UTF-8.

Comment: @egreg And the other errors...espacially the error at the beginning...

Comment: I know this problem and how to solve it. It is a general problem of Acrobat's preflight with PDFs generated by pdftex.